# Restrict output to only 3 lines in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter

How to restrict the content to only certain number of characters. I want to restrict the no of lines to 3 lines with 6 words each and with breaks to display the next 6 words in the next line. $row->openletter gives me complete result with more than 1000 words. I have loaded the text helper in the controller. Please find the attached image for what i want to achieve. How do i restrict $row->openletter to display only 6 words in each line and restrict no of lines to 3?

```html
<?php     
   echo "</li>";
  echo "</ul>"; 
 echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
 echo "<div class='news-v2-desc'>";
  echo "<h3>";
  <a href="<?php $this->load->helper('url'); echo base_url();?>index.php/Welcome/indexes?id=<?php $data=$row->open_id; echo $data; ?>">
   <?php $ima=$row->title; echo $ima; ?>
  </a>
  <?php echo "</h3>";
  echo "<small>By Admin | California, US | In <a href='#'>Art</a></small>";
  echo "<p>";
   $string = word_limiter($row->openletter, 4);
   echo  $string;
  echo "</p>";   
 echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: you need the output as shown in the image. i am right?

Comment: you need 6 words and three lines right

Comment: @how you accepted the answer of Abdulla. he did substing function. it wont satisfies your question. you asked for 6 word in each line that two 3 line . how it will work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$para = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.';

$pos = strpos($para, ' ', 200);
echo substr($para,0,$pos )
```

[Phpfiddle Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/f190e25bed8a74d50ca6)

Answer (score 1):

as per your question the  $string = $row->openletter; should divided into 3lines and 6 words per line. i think this code will satisfies your question. let me know the result

```
<?php
$string = "Here is a nice text string consisting of eleven words.Here is a nice text string consisting of eleven words";
$str=explode(' ',$string );//stores each word as a array 
$a=0;
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
$a=$a+$i;
$b=$a+1;
$c=$b+1;
$d=$c+1;
$e=$d+1;
$f=$e+1;
$a=$f;
echo $str[$a]." ".$str[$b]." ".$str[$c]." ".$str[$d]." ".$str[$e]." ".$str[$f];
echo"<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: @shank but you have accepted another answer have the problem solved?

Comment: @shank try the updated answer. let me know what is the output